# Where is the LDAP configuration in SharePoint online to use AD security groups for permissions?

Tags: ldap

Attempting to configure or find out how to configure the LDAP on Office 365/SharePoint Admin Console. We are wanting to use AD security groups to set permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on how aggressive your Azure AD Connect filters are. If these Security groups are not being synchronized, then you will have to modify your configuration to allow them to be synced to Office 365.

If you see them in your Admin portal under the Groups section, then they can be used in SharePoint groups for security.

Directory synchronization information can be found at https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home?switchtomoderndefault=true#/dirsyncmanagement in the admin portal.